# Is there an editor for Leaflet JavaScript that has intellisense functionality?

Tags: leaflet, javascript, visual-studio-code

Is there an editor for Leaflet JavaScript that has intellisense functionality?

I've tried both Visual Studio 2015 and Visual Studio Code ...

- in 2015, if I type code like `var geojsonlayer = L` and hit the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SPACE</kbd> combination for intellisense, I get offered  `Location (in lib.d.ts)` rather than `L.`
- I get no intellisense in VSC

Answer (score 1):

Limited success, but following seems to give at least some intellisense ...

- add a `_references.js` to the Visual Studio solution
- add a copy of the `leaflet-src.js`
- make sure the `_references.js` has `/// <reference path="leaflet-src.js" />` in it

But it's not 100%, so anything better?

Answer (score 1):

With Visual Studio code, if you have TypeScript definitions files for certain libraries, `/// <reference`-ing such a definition file will light up intellisense for that particular library in any JS/TypeScript file that has that reference tag.

For this to work in the case of leaflet, you need node.js installed and then.

- Make sure typings is installed `npm install -g typings`
- From the command line in your project directory, install the TypeScript definition file for leaflet `typings install dt~leaflet --global --save`
- Then in whatever JavaScript you require leaflet intellisense, just add a reference tag at the top of the file that points to `$PROJECT_DIR/typings/index.d.ts`

VSCode at this point should activate intellisense for leaflet on that JavaScript file.

[image: VS Code Leaflet intellisense]

Note that with this approach, the quality of the intellisense is a function of the quality of the TypeScript definition file for the library you're using. YMMV.